# how to transfer a data frame column into the format that tslearn needs?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, time

I am studying tslearn. But I am really confused about the input data format. Let's say there is a data frame:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'cla':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                'value':[1,2,3,4,2,4,1]})
```

I want a and b are the separate time series respectively. So, it looks like:

```
a: 1,2,3,4
b: 2,4,1
```

According to tslearn, the input example is:

```
X = to_time_series_dataset([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

So, how can I transfer the data to:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,4,1]]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try a.groupby('cla').value.agg(list).tolist()

Comment: @ ResidentSleeper. Thanks a lot. But it says: 'type' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`a.groupby('cla').agg(list)['value'].to_list()`

Comment: Thanks. I tried. It says: No objects to concatenate. I am running this code under databricks. But I think this should not be a problem?

Comment: Hey, for me this code is giving output as `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 1]]` exactly as required ..

Comment: Maybe because my code is under databricks. I will try it on my local machine. Thanks a lot